# Nginx redirect of subdomain routes not working

Tags: nginx, redirect

This is my server block in the nginx_conf file:

I'm using cloud66 so I can edit this from my dashboard.

This keeps breaking. I suspect it's because of my conditionals and if statements.

I'm trying to reroute the following urls to the following urls:

http://subdomain.domain.com/notes.php and route it to /dashboard
route it to
http://domain.com/dashboard

http://subdomain.domain.com/contact-us.php and route it to /dashboard
route it to
http://domain.com/contact-us/new

http://subdomain.domain.com/help.php and route it to /dashboard
route it to
http://domain.com/faq

```
server
{
...
    # redirect old routes on subdomain
    server_name ~^www\.(?<domain>.+)$;

    if ($host ~ "^(.*)$domain") {
      set $subd $1;

      if $1 = 'notes.php'{
        rewrite ^(.*) /dashboard permanent;
      }

      if $1 = 'contact-us.php'{
        rewrite ^(.*) /contact-us/new permanent;
      }

      if $1 = 'help.php'{
        rewrite ^(.*) /faq permanent;
      }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I put this:

```
+ server
+ {
+ server_name secure.inrtracker.com www.secure.inrtracker.com;
+
+ location = /notes.php {
+ rewrite ^ /dashboard permanent;
+ }
+ }
```

***An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.
If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
Faithfully yours, nginx.***

Answer (score 2):

First up: Obligatory [If is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)

Secondly you should separate your subdomain and domain to different server blocks (and / or different files). Then create rewrite rules

```
server {
    server_name oursubdomain.domain.com www.oursubdomain.domain.com;

    location / {
         rewrite ^/notes.php$ $scheme://domain.com/dashboard permanent;
         rewrite ^/contact-us.php$ $scheme://domain.com/contact-us/new permanent;
         rewrite ^/help.php$ $scheme://domain.com/faq permanent;
    }
}

server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    location = /dashboard {
        # Do something here, possibly send to php
    }
    location = /faq {
        # Do something here, possibly send to php
    }
    location = /contact-us/new {
        # Do something here, possibly send to php
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you on your way!

Comment: that gave us an error :(

Comment: What error? You could just copy the 3 rewrite lines into your first server block (on the subdomain), and it will work. Make sure you are closing your brackets and finishing lines with;

Comment: My solution still stands. Also for testing 30x errors you should use wget as it will show you each response it gets, either 301 or 302.
---
In the modification you are telling nginx to listen on /notes.php. Do you have a /dashboard location block? Also are you checking what  your error.log file shows when you visit the site?